# Jekyll sass file not compiling

Tags: css, sass, jekyll

I've set up a new Jekyll site to test the Neat 2.0 grid. However, as I run `Jekyll Serve` I've noticed that nothing from my `main.scss` file doesn't compile into my main.css file:(

**Folder set up**

[image]

**Config.yml**

```
sass:
  sass_dir: _scss
```

What's happening here and how can I get my main.scss file to compile?

Answer (score 5):

The `sass_dir` won't be processed by the sass converter directly, is only meant to contain [partials](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/assets/):

> sass_dir becomes the load path for Sass imports, nothing more. This
>   means that Jekyll does not know about these files directly (..)
>   This folder should only contain imports.

To have your *sass* file converted, start the file with two lines of triple dashes:

```
---
---

// sass content
```

The output file will be located in the directory where that file is placed.

You can put it in `css/main.scss` and Jekyll will generate `css/main.css`.

Comment: Now I get the following error -   `Conversion error: Jekyll::Converters::Scss encountered an error while converting 'assets/main.scss':
                    no implicit conversion of String into Integer
jekyll 3.4.2 | Error:  no implicit conversion of String into Integer`

Comment: That is another story, it seems you have an error in your scss file because Jekyll now found it and is trying to convert it.

Answer (score 1):

I am playing with this as well, but I'm a beginner, so take my advice with a pinch of salt.

However, my setup is working and compiling all scss changes when I'm running "jekyll serve --watch" with my _sass folder specified in config.yml as:

```
sass:
    sass_dir: _sass
```

My _sass folder itself contains a couple of _scss files, which I use for styling, but the important thing, I think, is that my jekyll CSS folder contains *only* imports in *only* one file named main.scss, like this:

```
 ---
 # Front matter comment to ensure Jekyll properly reads the file
 ---
 @import 
 "layout",
 "grids",
 "etc"
```

Hopefully this not-very-techinical explaination is of use either to you, or to someone googling how to make jekyll compile/process and watch for changes in .sccs files.

Comment: sass:
    sass_dir: _sass worked!